# Physics cross-simulation interactions?

Tags: fluid-simulation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

For example, rigid bodies and fluid. I know it's kind of possible by setting the rigid bodies as fluid obstacles, but it's not "true" interaction in that the fluid does not affect the rigid bodies...

By "true" interaction I mean where two (or more) physics systems affect each other simultaneously. For example, with rigid body and cloth, the rigid body affects the cloth but the cloth doesn't affect the rigid body (at least the way I'm doing it), so the rigid body just eventually stretches the cloth to an extreme and falls through...

Are there any ways to achieve this? (for any interaction, not just rigid bodies and fluid)

Or, if not, does anyone know whether there are any plans to implement this sort of feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no way to do true cross-simulation between the different physics systems right now. And I do not know of any on-going project that will bring about that functionality as of this time.

Comment: Bummer!!! but I guess it is super duper hard thing to implement

Comment: See my answer here.  Some things are possible, also [water onto cloth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/286659/111042)

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes possible with some tricks that bind other (non-rendered) objects affected by one physics to another set of physics.

Here for example I use an object that is shrinkwrapped to a fluid surface, to allow a cloth object to float on top once it "hits" the shrinkwrapped (plane) object:

[image: cloth floats on plance shrinkwrapped to water mesh]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not all physics can be cross-simulated -- that's true.  Some can and some others can with "tricks" (cloth floating on water).  Here I simulated a bucket of water (flow:goemetry) onto a cloth that has added Solidify and then Fluid effector/collision, in that exact ordering on the stack.

[image]

My example: [image]