# Rigid body simulation with a fluid spill simulation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

I just want to make a simple animation of an tomato hitting a surface and spills over it like that.
[image]
I already imported tomato object, made it rigid and it hits surfaces. I just don't know how to make it break open and spills over yet not leave the solid tomato.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use rigid body simulation for this? It looks like it might be better suited to a fluid simulation..

Comment: I think you are right but still dont know how to use fluid sim effect to make this

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5305/599

Comment: STILL DIDN FIND THE ANSWER