# Stop fluid animation at certain frame

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation

I can't find a way to stop fluid animation at frame 150 while I have 250 frames in total and wondering how I can do so.

Comment: Citing manual (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/domain.html): "Start and end times have nothing to do with how many frames are baked, If you set Start time to 3.0, and End time to 4.0, you will simulate 1 second of fluid motion. That one second of fluid motion will be spread across however-many frames are set in Render ‣ Dimensions."... so maybe you coul use a separate shorter scene, then link the baked sim in the real scene, maybe?

Comment: @eddyuk read this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5306/1853