# How to make swimming pool in blender that has a dense volume of water?

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing

I am making a project in which an object dives in a swimming pool in order to find out water depth and density. I need guidance that **

> how to make swimming pool in blender that has a dense volume of
>   water?

**
Any guidance in this would be so appreciating.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by dense? Are you looking for fluid simulation? (e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5305/599)

Comment: Are you looking for the actual water material instructions or the whole modeling and material?

Comment: Yes, actual water material instruction.