# How to make an object to float on the water (fluid simulation, not ocean modifier)?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, dynamic-paint

How to make the object to float on the water (fluid simulation, not ocean modifier) such as the leaf of a tree? I tried two options that work with ocean modifier (https://youtu.be/11F1NRpqrzY?t=8m43s , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfi7HW8qHAo) but they both give incorrect results. In addition, if they would work, they would make the leaf float on the surface of the water, staying in one place, and I want the water to cerry the leaf, as a physical object.

Comment: possibly related to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5937/is-it-possible-to-float-an-object-on-a-fluid-simulation

Comment: @m.ardito Yes, it is... so looks like there is no way to make an object to float on the fluid?..

Comment: maybe not (yet?), your'not the first to ask, on the net. I just found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lk-iPI6KwZc and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfi7HW8qHAo, maybe the second may help you...?

Comment: @m.ardito Thank you very much for the links! I tried the second method, in my tests it works not so well with fluid, and I think it is not suitable for complex situations (e.g. a mountain stream or a waterfall), but it seems to be the only compromise option yet. I think the first option, can also be used (I didn't try it yet, though) - you can use the fluid particle system from the first video to make an object move with the flow, and then disable renderer of the particle system, leaving only the object and fluid simulation. And set the object as fluid obstacle to make water interact with it.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you already had the other link... I have another (crazy) idea, just have to check if it can work... I'll let you know.

Comment: I can't make work my idea, which was: use boolean to intersect a cube with the fluid sim result, obtaining a solid surface which always has the fluid shape. Then use rigid body to make "the boat" to "sit" over that solid surface using rigid bodies, simulating "float". It seems someone can make it work but even better or simpler, search the net for "blender fluid sim and rigif bodies". Eg: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLwYWW2N16w (this is not blender, probably)

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Try setting up a fluid simulation that includes a small amount of floater particles. I add a cube into the fluid domain and put it on a second layer and associate it with generating fluid floater particles. Fluid boundary needs at least 1 subdivision, and I think you have to activate at least 1 tracer under fluid particles, try a small generate number like 0.1. You could delete the resulting few particles to leave only one. Then use a particle instance modifier to connect your floating mesh object to the singular particle.