# How to make the sphere which falls into simulated water be deformed by this water too?

Tags: fluid-simulation, surface-deform

There are tutorials telling how to make a liquid simulation. Also demonstrating the objects which fall into water creating splashes, waves, etc.
I want to step ahead a bit: how to make the object which falls into water get deformed, too? I.e. I want water and this object to deform each other (imagine this object made of some pretty soft substance - jelly or whatetever).

Comment: Alas you want what cannot be accomplished at this time with blender.  There are some physics that cannot interact.  Rigid Body physics is sort of isolated from other things, while you can still assign a Collision modifier to a RB, a RB can only interact or be affected by another RB.

Comment: Reference: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5939/111042  I also see you're trying to use an SD modifier: that won't work either.