# Irregularly-shaped rigid bodies and molecular particles?

Tags: particles, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm using [PyroEvil](http://pyroevil.com/category/scripts-addons/molecular-script/)'s molecular addon to have a bunch of particles collide with each other and the environment. However, I also have some other objects in the environment which I'd like to get to react with the particles (e.g. plates, cups, food)

I could create another few particle systems and make each object another particle, but Blender's particle system only supports spherical particles and the collision would look absurd.

So, how can I make molecular particles collide with irregularly-shaped objects and have them move about?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with the addon, but you can make any object affect particles by adding *Collision* physics to it in the physics panel.

Comment: @gandalf3 Yep, the objects affect the particles, but I want vice-versa as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible at the moment, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/989/599 :/