# How close is fluid simulation to being able to influence rigid bodies?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

I embarked on a project to use Blender to simulate the behaviour of a wave energy device in order to establish its performance, only to find while learning fluid simulation that fluids cannot affect solid objects. This is fatal to this project, and disappointing as Blender has everything else. How close is fluid simulation to being able to influence rigid objects (eg, chairs and cars being washed away by a flood, or water turning a water wheel)? If not currently in development or scheduled, where is the place to start to pursue enhancing Blender to incorporate this capability myself?

Comment: AFAIK there is [no active development](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/989/599) in this area, but as a blender user I can say that such a feature would be a more than welcome addition! You might ask on the [development mailing list](http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-committers), see [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact).

Comment: Thanks for that. Have emailed one of the fluid simulation developers as a next step.