# Is it possible to get a rigid body to bounce off cloth?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I am doing something very basic: trying to simulate a rigid body (a sphere) falling onto a large cloth. Right now in my simulation, the object falls, the cloth deforms, and then the object just comes to rest on the cloth. It would look more realistic if the sphere were to bounce a little bit (and maybe roll around) before coming completely to rest. I have tried changing the physics properties of the cloth and the rigid body, with no success. I know rigid bodies can bounce off of each other: is there any way to get them to bounce off of a cloth before coming to a stop?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/989/599