# Combining two different physics in one object?

Tags: materials, physics

I would like to create a fixed cylinder made of a non deformable material, for example steel, which has a membrane at its bottom, rubber or so, which is nonpermeabel. If I fill the cylinder with a fluid, e.g. water, I want the membrane to behave like a real one would, to let me see the force of the waterpressure lasting on it. So with rising water level the membrane should start to curve.

Sorry, it´s a bit difficult for me to express what I actually want, but I guess  you´re able to get it.

I used a circle, which I extruded in z-direction and selected the bottom face but that made the whole object as a cloth. I also declared the whole object as cloth, defined the upper part as vertex-group and tried to fix just the upper part, but that also didn't work. I also defined the torso as a material and the bottom too but didn't find any possibility to assign different physics to both materials.
Does anyone have an idea what I could try to get the effect I want to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Physics cross-simulation interactions?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/989/physics-cross-simulation-interactions)

Comment: You won't get a fluid sim going into a tube effect the results of a soft body sim. You should be able to fake it to some degree. Most sim properties can be keyframed to vary during an animation. Cloth sim can pin vertices in a vertex group that will not be affected by the sim. Soft body can also use vertex groups to define goal weight. You can use vertex weight modifiers or dynamic paint to alter the vertex weight over time.