# Rigid body not interacting with cloth

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

Not sure if that's a noob question, as I'm just getting started on simulations…

I have a sphere with cloth physics and inside it I placed some more spheres with rigid body + collision physics (they are close together so when the simulation starts they have an initial push). I need the rigid bodies to stay inside the cloth sphere, but they just fly through it. Any ideas?

Other details:

- I've turned gravity off
- I intend on using internal pressure on the cloth sphere to make inflate and deflate, will this interfere with anything?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Physics cross-simulation interactions?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1030/111042