# cloth and rigid body collision sim, center of mass not updating properly

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision

one of the cylinders is rigid body, another is cloth, I've made them interact with each other and also the cloth sheet and ground underneath, but the center of mass is not updating properly which causes the three active objects react too quickly ,here is the blend file, how to make the center of mass update properly?

[image]

Comment: Apparently not: Physics cross-simulation interactions?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1030/111042