# Can particles and fluid interact?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I would like to drop particles in a fluid,
the particles should be integrated in the fluid,
a bit like when cooking, mixing chocolate chips into cookie dough.

Is this possible in blender ? I know how to create a fluid simulation with a viscous liquid,
I know how to create a particles system,
but they don't interact with each other, although I've added Collision physics property to the liquid domain.
Test file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rwBNAOTl5x8gvy4Sl_Yd4KmDj0F2T-F4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is still true today:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1030/111042 and I do wish the documentation would state so in the introduction, so when this comes along we'll hear bells ringing!

Comment: Hmm, try organizing the physics panels so that the collision thing is at the bottom? Or…

Comment: There might be a way to fake what you want. I’ve definitely seen a link somewhere to tips and tricks on making fluid look right. Try using a hair particle system on a hidden mesh shrink wrapped to the fluid from above then booleaned by the container.

Comment: Or just skip the particle bit and have some object chips snapping to the fluid mesh from above. Then you could have them shuffle around by animation.

Comment: thanks ZargulTheWizard, your proposal #1 does not appear to change anything to my sim. The more I read about this the more I believe comment from @james_t, 2 sims can't impact each other. As for your proposal #3, it would certainly work, but require a lot of work as I have many particles involved. As for your proposal #2, I'm trying to wrap my brain around it, a bit above my level for now.