# Is it possible to affect a cloth simulation with fluid simulation?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, cloth-simulation

I am trying to simulate fluid on top of baked cloth simulation. It is even possible?

I have got a baked cloth sim with a FLIP Fluid physics sets to obstacle and a sphere set as fluid that drops on top of the cloth. All within a domain.

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
T.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/989/physics-cross-simulation-interactions

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that answer is from 2013. Nothing has change since then?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos see my answer and also my [cloth on water](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/286657/111042) example.

Comment: Do you mean: "want the water to flow over the cloth"?  Or: "want the falling water to further move the cloth around"?

Answer (score 0):

Not all physics can be cross-simulated -- that's true.  Yours can and some others can with "tricks" (cloth floating on water).  Here I simulated a bucket of water (flow:goemetry) onto a cloth that has added Solidify and then Fluid effector/collision, in that exact ordering on the stack.

[image]

My example: [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When posting here please avoid text inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be searched for or readily found in the future. It can't also be easily edited in case of errors or typos, nor updated when it gets outdated in case of future changes. Maybe add an [image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) of the results. ;)

Comment: Don't hesitate to ping me if you update the answer, curious to see the results

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos -- the original image includes the results, but in wire-frame mode so that one can see the layers.  The orange wireframe is the cloth-sim result, and the wireframe with blue dots is the liquid.  I also include the blend file!  You have been pinged ;)